# Appending Point Shapefile Location by GPS values in text file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, shapefile

In my industry it is common to create preliminary design maps for point locations that have a unique identifier. Upon the actual construction on the design, points change location based on construction.

Is there any way in ArcGIS 10.0 Editor license to append the new XY information (update the geometry) for those points? Python is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following script that will update a point location. You'll have to flesh it out for a full program, but it's a start:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "Workspace/Path"
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Feature_Class", "ID = 'xxxx'") //just an example, you can use any query
pnt = arcpy.Point()
pnt.X = 100
pnt.Y = 100
shpfield = arcpy.Describe("Feature_Class").shapeFieldName
for row in cur:
     row.setValue(shpfield,pnt)
     cur.updateRow(row)

del row,cur,pnt
```

Man page at http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/UpdateCursor/000v0000003m000000/